# GWT Login using SPRING + Simple HTML page

Tags: spring, gwt, authentication

my name is Lukas and I have one issue with login. I am using GWT + Spring and I want to authenticate. I found lot of examples on google, but neither scenario was same like mine.

I have Login.html containing HTML form with input ant their names (j_username, j_password). I have Login.gwt.xml file renamed to "login" (Login.html also contains `<script type="text/javascript" src="login/login.nocache.js" ></script>` ). My project also contains SecondModule.html file + SecondModule.gwt.xml (renamed to "myModule"). The second module is reponsible for business logic.

My problem is I dont know how to specify URL parameter in HTML form element in Login.html. I have tried /login/j_security_check, /j_security_check, /myModule/j_security_check but I always get Error code 404. I also dont know if that URL differs in development or hosted mode.

Can anybody help me?

Regards Lukas

Answer (score 0):

In spring you should use

```
/j_spring_security_check
```

Comment: Yeah my fault, but if I tried /j_spring_security_check or /login/j_spring_security_check or /myModule/j_spring_security_check same result. Response 404

Comment: do you have a POST method in your form? You should probably look in spring security configuration to ensure that it really starts, as from the provided info I can only guess. BTW what is the role of the Login gwt module if you have only the login form on this page?

Comment: I have POST method specified in form. The reason is that we are using this GWT web application skeleton for other applications and  we want to have it separated. Previous login page was done without HTML form element (+AJAX) and there is a bug that browser is not storing filled username/pass. I am replacing this with <form> and also making this login as a separate module. But still problem with that URL.

Comment: Problem solved. You have to send form to URL which is defined in login-processing-url="/login" .